# iOS 15 Swift AttributedString markdown code blocks

Tags: swift, markdown, uilabel, uitextview, ios15

iOS 15 has the new AttributedString API:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring

It doesn't seem to support code blocks with markdown.  Does anyone know how to show code blocks using that?

I've been using a cocoapod (MarkdownKit), but it's not great at it.

Hoping for something similar to stack overflow code blocks:

````
```
Here's a code block
```
````

Comment: I guess it's not supported. See the comments over here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682711?answerId=678926022#678926022